# can not sending mail with exim4 in debian

Tags: email, debian, exim

I have installed exim4 using `aptitude install exim4`

and configured it with `dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config`

this is my `/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf` file:

```
dc_eximconfig_configtype='internet'
dc_other_hostnames='midomain.com'
dc_local_interfaces='127.0.0.1 ; ::1'
dc_readhost=''
dc_relay_domains=''
dc_minimaldns='false'
dc_relay_nets=''
dc_smarthost=''
CFILEMODE='644'
dc_use_split_config='false'
dc_hide_mailname='true'
dc_mailname_in_oh='true'
dc_localdelivery='maildir_home'
```

when I exec in shell: `echo "This is a test." | mail -s Testing mygmailaddress@gmail.com`

it does nothing.

in the `/var/log/exim4/mainlog` I can see the following error:

```
2012-08-04 13:05:30 1SxcAk-0001BT-61 <= root@ETC_MAILNAME U=root P=local S=494
2012-08-04 13:05:30 1SxcAk-0001BT-61 ** mygmailaddress@gmail.com: Unrouteable address
2012-08-04 13:05:30 1SxcAk-0001BV-Al Error while reading message with no usable sender address (R=1SxcAk-0001BT-61): at least one malformed recipient address: root@ETC_MAILNAME - malformed address: _MAILNAME may not follow root@ETC
2012-08-04 13:05:30 1SxcAk-0001BT-61 Process failed (1) when writing error message to root@ETC_MAILNAME (frozen)
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the file `/etc/mailname` does not exist.  This should contain one line consisting of the FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name) that your host should be known as.

If you don't have a fixed IP address with properly configured rDNS records, I strongly suggest you use a smarthost.  Usually your ISP provides a relay server you can use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run:

```
update-exim4.conf --keepcomments --output /etc/exim4/exim4.conf
```

So debconf will go through and fill in all those values...

https://wiki.debian.org/Exim#Your_own_file